# How to change the path of the jre in mac

Tags: java, macos

I've a java project where I'm referencing a security file abc.pem in my java security folder:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/abc.pem
```

When I deploy my project on different linux servers, I've to store the abc.pem file in the following path on the server:

```
/usr/java/default/jre/lib/security/abc.pem
```

How can I modify the path in my local machine from

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/abc.pem
```

to

```
/usr/java/default/jre/lib/security/abc.pem
```

I'm using a mac

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to fix this issue by changing where you deploy the pem file (so that it follows the JDK), than by changing where you install the JDK (so that it follows the pem file)?

Comment: I cannot change where to deploy the pem file because all the remote servers where I'm deploying my project contains this path: /usr/java/default/jre/lib/security/abc.pem

Comment: Obviously. And on Windows it's going to be somewhere in `C:\Program Files`. Point is, you're better off making sure your installation script can handle different environments than going into unusual and undocumented alternative installation locations on your Mac. The problem isn't your Mac; it's your installation script.